# An unorthodox riddle

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Imagine that you are trapped in a completely wooden room that has no doors, windows, or any openings.

The only object in the room is a wooden table. How do you escape?

(For every wrong answer, I will add a hint.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Break the table in halves. Two halves make a hole. Go through the hole.

Comment: Oh don't worry! It happens often here as people rush to post the same answer :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @jkl3699 several reasons. 1 you accepted this answer so my answer was no longer needed, 2. Me and several others remember seeing this puzzle here before, so we think this may be a dupe and will be closed, and dupes don't need answers. (We haven't found the post yet, so the puzzle will remain open for now)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Well, In case you are wondering, I was not aware that this could be a possible duplicate.

Comment: @jkl3699 oh don't worry, we know you didn't post a dupe on purpose. As it is it seems that the original post here has been deleted so this will remain open anyway (though it is a famous problem which can be found else where in the internet)

Comment: If you have sufficient karate skills to break the wooden table without any tools, why don't you just break one of the walls?

Comment: @A.P. I would assume that the walls are too thick.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't strong enough to break a wooden table by hand, you might need something extra in addition to kraby15's answer:

1. > Rub your hands together until they're **sore**.
2. > Take the **saw** and cut the wooden table in half.
3. > Two halves make a **whole**. Jump through the **hole** to escape.

And if you need to get further away ...

4. > Shout and shout until you're **hoarse**. Get on the **horse** and gallop away.